# How to load .html file, located in relative path/shared folders to PyQt5 browser widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, relative-path

I'm trying to load a .html file that contains plotly plot >2mb size.File is located in shared folder.
QUrl.fromLocalfile() is not working as file is in remote location.
After using QUrl.fromLocalFile(QFileInfo().absoluteFilePath()) browser appears blank

```
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl,QFileInfo
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidgets
    from PyQt5.WebEngineWidgets import QWebengineView

    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser=QWebEngineView()
    filepath=QUrl.fromLocalFile(QFileInfo("\\path\to\shared\folder\plot.html").absoluteFilePath())
    browser.load(filepath)
    browser.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Escape the backslash characters.